# Pandas, фильтр по количеству типов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

подскажите, пожалуйста, как отфильтровать, есть таблица:

```
фича    фича   тип
  1       1      0
  2       2      1
  2       2      1
  3       3      5
  3       3      5
  7       7      3
```

хочется убрать из таблицы все типы данных, которых суммарно не больше 1:

как в примере, тип - 0 и тип - 3 их всего по одному,
хочется эти данные удалить и оставить только те которых больше одного.

вот я хотел так, но это не работает по понятным причинам, но передает смысл затеи:

```
df[df['types'].value_counts() > 1]
```

хотелось бы что бы получилось так:

```
фича    фича   тип
  2       2      1
  2       2      1
  3       3      5
  3       3      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'fich1': [1,2,2,3,3,7],
     'fich2': [1,2,2,3,3,7],
     'type': [0,1,1,5,5,3]
 })

print (df)
df['count'] = df.groupby('type')['type'].transform('count')
print (df)
df= df.loc[df['count'] >1]
print (df)
```

Для наглядности создаем колонку count и производим фильтрацию таблицы по ней

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно существует два наиболее идиоматических варианта.

1. используя [DataFrame.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

   ```
   In [13]: df[df.duplicated('type', keep=False)]
   Out[13]:
      feature1  feature2  type
   1         2         2     1
   2         2         2     1
   3         3         3     5
   4         3         3     5
   ```
2. как уже ответил @Phil, используя `df.groupby().transform('...')`. Создавать дополнительный столбец необязательно:

   ```
   In [12]: df[df.groupby('type')['type'].transform('size') > 1]
   Out[12]:
      feature1  feature2  type
   1         2         2     1
   2         2         2     1
   3         3         3     5
   4         3         3     5
   ```